# Creating loop to parse table data in scrapy

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to loop through the table rows with the following HTML. I am using the following xpath selector `//*[@id="employee-table"]/tbody/tr` but it doesn't work.

```
<table id="employee-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered responsive-table dataTable no-footer" role="grid" aria-describedby="employee-table_info" style="width: 882px;">
<thead>
<tr role="row"><th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="employee-table" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label=" Name : activate to sort column descending" style="width: 174px;"> Name </th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="employee-table" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label=" Year : activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 36px;"> Year </th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="employee-table" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label=" Title : activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 82px;"> Title </th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="employee-table" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label=" Agency : activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 192px;"> Agency </th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="employee-table" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label=" Location : activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 115px;"> Location </th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="employee-table" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label=" Salary : activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 50px;"> Salary </th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr role="row" class="odd"><td class="sorting_1"><a href="/employees/veterans-health-administration/bharatkumar-a-g">A G. Bharatkumar</a></td><td>2015</td><td><a href="/employees/occupations/medical-officer">Medical Officer</a></td><td><a href="/employees/veterans-health-administration">Veterans Health Administration</a></td><td>Wisconsin</td><td>$335,000</td></tr><tr role="row" class="even"><td class="sorting_1"><a href="/employees/veterans-health-administration/roure-a-rafael">A Rafael Roure</a></td><td>2015</td><td><a href="/employees/occupations/medical-officer">Medical Officer</a></td><td><a href="/employees/veterans-health-administration">Veterans Health Administration</a></td><td>Florida</td><td>$333,634</td></tr><tr role="row" class="odd"><td class="sorting_1"><a href="/employees/veterans-health-administration/dumont-aaron-s">Aaron S. Dumont</a></td><td>2015</td><td><a href="/employees/occupations/medical-officer">Medical Officer</a></td><td><a href="/employees/veterans-health-administration">Veterans Health Administration</a></td><td>Louisiana</td><td>$330,302</td></tr><tr role="row" class="even"><td class="sorting_1"><a href="/employees/veterans-health-administration/andrews-aaron-t">Aaron T. Andrews</a></td><td>2015</td><td><a href="/employees/occupations/medical-officer">Medical Officer</a></td><td><a href="/employees/veterans-health-administration">Veterans Health Administration</a></td><td>Florida</td><td>$350,000</td></tr><tr role="row" class="odd"><td class="sorting_1"><a href="/employees/veterans-health-administration/elmi-abdolali">Abdolali Elmi</a></td><td>2015</td><td><a href="/employees/occupations/medical-officer">Medical Officer</a></td><td><a href="/employees/veterans-health-administration">Veterans Health Administration</a></td><td>West Virginia</td><td>$325,056</td></tr><tr role="row" class="even"><td class="sorting_1"><a href="/employees/veterans-health-administration/haleem-abdul-a">Abdul A. Haleem</a></td><td>2015</td><td><a href="/employees/occupations/medical-officer">Medical Officer</a></td><td><a href="/employees/veterans-health-administration">Veterans Health Administration</a></td><td>Missouri</td><td>$351,056</td></tr><tr role="row" class="odd"><td class="sorting_1"><a href="/employees/veterans-health-administration/ward-abner-m">Abner M. Ward</a></td><td>2015</td><td><a href="/employees/occupations/medical-officer">Medical Officer</a></td><td><a href="/employees/veterans-health-administration">Veterans Health Administration</a></td><td>Hawaii</td><td>$337,756</td></tr><tr role="row" class="even"><td class="sorting_1"><a href="/employees/veterans-health-administration/cohen-adam-c">Adam C. Cohen</a></td><td>2015</td><td><a href="/employees/occupations/medical-officer">Medical Officer</a></td><td><a href="/employees/veterans-health-administration">Veterans Health Administration</a></td><td>Indiana</td><td>$340,000</td></tr><tr role="row" class="odd"><td class="sorting_1"><a href="/employees/veterans-health-administration/bakker-adam-j">Adam J. Bakker</a></td><td>2015</td><td><a href="/employees/occupations/medical-officer">Medical Officer</a></td><td><a href="/employees/veterans-health-administration">Veterans Health Administration</a></td><td>Minnesota</td><td>$325,980</td></tr><tr role="row" class="even"><td class="sorting_1"><a href="/employees/veterans-health-administration/bracha-adam-s">Adam S. Bracha</a></td><td>2015</td><td><a href="/employees/occupations/medical-officer">Medical Officer</a></td><td><a href="/employees/veterans-health-administration">Veterans Health Administration</a></td><td>Florida</td><td>$335,000</td></tr></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It worked for me using `lxml` => `r = tree.xpath('//*[@id="employee-table"]/tbody/tr')`

Comment: Try using this selector `//*[@id="employee-table"]/tbody/tr[@role="row"]`

Answer (score 2):

Try `//*[@id="employee-table"]/tr`

The reason of why your xpath doesn't work is becuase of `tbody`. You have to remove it and check if you get that result that you want.

You can read this in scrapy documentation: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.14/topics/firefox.html

> Firefox, in particular, is known for adding `<tbody>` elements to
>   tables. Scrapy, on the other hand, does not modify the original page
>   HTML, so you won’t be able to extract any data if you use `<tbody>` in
>   your XPath expressions.